# C - Struct pass value - Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, struct

Where is the error in **list->qtag->label=x;** while trying to put value in label?

```
struct quad{

        int label;
        char op[30];
        char x[30];
        char y[30];
        char z[30];
        struct quad *next;
};

struct tag{

        struct quad *qtag;
        struct tag *next2;
};

struct tag *makelist(int x){

        struct tag *list;
        list=(struct tag*)malloc(sizeof(struct tag));
        list->qtag->label=x;
        printf("!\n");
        return list;
};
```

Comment: Where did you allocate memory for `*(list->qtag)`?

Comment: ..which you would have spotted very quickly if you had bothered to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize that `qtag` in your `list`. Could be fixed like this:

```
list=(struct tag*)malloc(sizeof(struct tag));
list->qtag = (struct quad*)malloc(sizeof(struct quad));
list->qtag->label = x;
```

Do not forget to check the return values of `malloc()` for possible errors.

Answer (score 0):

you have allocated memory for your inital tag entry - but you have not initialised that data to anything. with malloc the data contents could well be random. Specifically list -> qtag is not pointing to anything, as you haven't pointed it to anything.

You either need to to initialise list -> qtag to point to an exsiting quad structure, or malloc another chunk of memory - and point list -> qtag to it - for instance :

```
struct tag *makelist(int x){

    struct tag *list;
    list=(struct tag*)malloc(sizeof(struct tag));
    q = (struct quad*)malloc(sizeof(struct quad));
    list->qtag = q;
    list->qtag->label=x;
    printf("!\n");
    return list;

};
```